# How to load content of one frame into another frame without reintializing current frame content

Tags: c#, .net, windows, win-universal-app

In my UWP I am trying to set content of Frame with another frame content but none of my solutions is working, what actually I am doing is from one Page I am passing Frame as a navigation parameter and on second page I have another frame which content I need to set with the frame in navigation parameter.

Here are the solutions that I tried:

Approach 1:

```
            var frame = e.Parameter as Frame;
            if (frame != null)
            {
                var contentPage = frame.SourcePageType;
                if (contentPage != null)
                    ContentFrame.Content = contentPage;
            }
```

Approach 2:

```
            var frame = e.Parameter as Frame;
            if (frame != null)
            {
                var contentPage = frame.SourcePageType;
                if (contentPage != null)
                    ContentFrame.Navigate(contentPage);
            }
```

Approach 1 does not work at all, while approach 2 is reintiating frame content which I don't want to.

Is there any other way I can set content of 1 frame to another.

Answer (score 0):

There are too much details missing from your question, but it looks like you don't have a clear separation of view, data and logic. Have you ever looked at MVVM ([see this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj721615(v=vs.105).aspx)). By using constructs like this, it's not a bad thing to rebuild UI again, as the data is still at a single place.

---

if this is an answer to your question, please mark this as answer.

Comment: Basically I just want content of one frame to set with content of another, you are right that rebuild UI doen't have much impact, but want to know if somehow we can just directly set another frame content without redrawing.

Comment: why Frame1.Content = Frame2.Content is not setting content of frame2 to frame1?